# Applet JavaScript Communication

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

On my web page I am running an applet and in order to warn user for certain inputs to the applet, I am using printing the errors to the html page. In order to do this I am using javascript applet communication. Below is the code for the Javascript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter=0;

function RemoveAppletErrorMessage()
{
    var AppletErrorTag=document.getElementById("AppletErrorMessages");
    if(AppletErrorTag!=null)
    {
        document.body.removeChild(AppletErrorTag);
    }
}

function updateWebPage(s)
{
    if(counter>=1) RemoveAppletErrorMessage();
    var parag=document.createElement('P');
    parag.setAttribute("id","AppletErrorMessages");
    var txt=document.createTextNode(s);
    parag.appendChild(txt);
    document.body.appendChild(parag);
    counter++;
}
</script>
```

Here, the Javascript function updateWebPage(s) function is called from the Java applet when a JButton is clicked with the following code:

```
if(jso != null && !errorMessage.isEmpty())
try {
    jso.call("updateWebPage", new String[] {errorMessage});
    return;
}
catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

In terms of communication everything works fine. However, when the JButton is clicked the second time, I am trying to clear up the error messages with RemoveAppletErrorMessage() calling from updateWebPage(s). It seems like every time I hit the JButton the error messages are appended to the web page which I do not want. I have tried to clear it with .innerHTML='' which did not work in the first place, so I changed my strategy to adding a node and checking if the node exists, clearing that node and adding again. What might be going on wrong?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you're appending to your errorMessage variable in Java?

Comment: At the end of public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) function I use the expression errorMessage=""; which I expect to clear the contents of the string.

Comment: Open developer tools and check whether your paragraph is actually removed from DOM. Also, put a breakpoint to updateWebPage method to see if you're getting the right s value.

Comment: I was indeed appending the error messages and seems like the expression errorMessage="" does not make the String an empty one. Also I have changed my javascript code to function updateWebPage(s)
{
 var parag=document.getElementById("AppletErrorMessages");
 parag.innerHTML='';
 parag.innerHTML=s;
}

Answer (score 0):

I'd open a div with an id of AppletErrorMessages and use jQuery in my updateWebPage() function like this (e.g. stop creating a new paragraph every time).

```
function updateWebPage(s)
{
  $("#AppletErrorMessages").html(s);
}
```